# subprocess stdout into a variable for Ngrok

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, stdout, popen, ngrok

I'm trying to make a Python script which reports me the port on 0.tcp.ngrok.io is started when I run the code on terminal (after moving ngrok executable file to /usr/local/bin)

`ngrok tcp 22`

I get this kind of output

```
ngrok by @inconshreveable                                       (Ctrl+C to quit)
                                                                                
Session Status                connecting                                        
Version                       2.2.4                                             
Region                        United States (us)                                
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4041                             
Forwarding                    tcp://0.tcp.ngrok.io:13014 -> localhost:22                                                                                 
Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90       
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

My first attempt is to log the subprocess stdout to a variable , but as the stdout is cyclic the stdout.read() never ends this is the code

```
import subprocess

ngrok = subprocess.Popen(['ngrok','tcp','22'],stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

output_text = ngrok.stdout.read() # script stops here forever

[**code for getting domain:port from output_text**]
```

how can I get a "snapshot" of stdout to a variable , without stopping ngrok?

Is there another way of doing this (next try would be a webscraper on localhost, but it would be nice to have this knowledge for other commands, such as "top")

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was working with `ngrok http` and all the alternatives weren't working, resulting in deadlocks and I even could print the child process response created with ngrok. Thus, reading the [ngrok docs](https://ngrok.com/docs#list-tunnels) I notice that there is a way to get the ngrok public url with requests.
Adding the code below:

```
localhost_url = "http://localhost:4041/api/tunnels" #Url with tunnel details
tunnel_url = requests.get(localhost_url).text #Get the tunnel information
j = json.loads(tunnel_url)
tunnel_url = j['Tunnels'][0]['PublicUrl'] #Do the parsing of the get
```

So, tunnel_url will return what you need. Adding the imports the full code would be like this:

```
import subprocess
import requests
import json

ngrok = subprocess.Popen(['ngrok','tcp','22'],stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

localhost_url = "http://localhost:4041/api/tunnels" #Url with tunnel details
tunnel_url = requests.get(localhost_url).text #Get the tunnel information
j = json.loads(tunnel_url)

tunnel_url = j['Tunnels'][0]['PublicUrl'] #Do the parsing of the get
```

Answer (score 1):

*not enough reputation to comment, feel free to update or comment on @Rodolfo great answer and then delete this*

Perhaps they've changed the api slightly, this is what worked for me:
(ngrok executable next to the script, serving http on port 5000 and picking the https tunneling url)

```
import subprocess
import requests
import json
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ngrok = subprocess.Popen(['./ngrok','http','5000'], 
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    time.sleep(3) # to allow the ngrok to fetch the url from the server
    localhost_url = "http://localhost:4040/api/tunnels" #Url with tunnel details
    tunnel_url = requests.get(localhost_url).text #Get the tunnel information
    j = json.loads(tunnel_url)

    tunnel_url = j['tunnels'][1]['public_url'] #Do the parsing of the get
    print(tunnel_url)
```

Comment: Here is an archived [link](https://archive.ph/4r2zU) to the docs

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
def open_tunnel():
        process = subprocess.Popen(f'/snap/bin/ngrok tcp {PORT} --log "stdout"', shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)  # You can also use a list and put shell = False
        while True:
            output = process.stdout.readline()
            if not output and process.poll() is not None:
                break
            elif b'url=' in output:
                output = output.decode()
                output = output[output.index('url=tcp://') + 10 : -1]
                return output.split(':')
```

I use `/snap/bin/ngrok` because my pycharm does not recognize path, sorry for that. You can replace it by saying only `ngrok`
.